# Git DevOps integration with Databricks Repos - random outstanding changes on master immediately after repo clone

Tags: git, devops, databricks, azure-repos, databricks-repos

Sometimes there are some random outstanding changes on master branch, immediately after cloning git DevOps repository to Azure Databricks resource. It seems like these changes have to be in white spaces because in chnages log I can see that the algorithm is deleteing and adding the same lines of text.

I can't commit them - because we have a policy on master branch.
I can't discart them.
I can't checkout to another branch.

I tried commit chnages from another branch but they are re-occuring in different files with new flow of commits.

[image]

Comment: maybe these are end-of-line encoding changes?

Comment: It's possible but I can't check it out. I can download a source file from Azure DevOps but not from Databricks Repos. Nevertheless, If I clone repo several times I get different number of files with outstanding changes. It happens only for arbitrary files (not for databricks notebooks) For the first clone I have 5 modified files, for the second only 2 modified files and then for the third clone I get again 5 modified files. All the modified files are repeating. I have no idea where this inconsistency is coming from.